# i Needed to solve the problem plz help

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets, superscripts

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 RresT (u) =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{\RresT (u)=   \Bigg\{ 1,  \text{ if Pos. {Arcs_{v_{\xrightarrow[]{}}u \ (u)} > Neg.Arcs_{v_{\xrightarrow[]{}}u}  (u)}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: this code is not working. can anybody let me know what I am missing? help me please]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Not an exact replica of your screenshot, but hopefully something usable:

[image]

In the code shown below, note that I've omitted some deadwood code, such as `\RresT (u)=   \Bigg\{ 1,`, and replaced both instances of `v_{\xrightarrow[]{}}u` with `v \to u`. I've also rendered `RresT`, `Pos.Arcs`, and `Neg.Arcs` in upright lettering.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{RresT}(u) =
   \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if } \mathrm{Pos.Arcs}_{v \to u} (u) 
                    >\mathrm{Neg.Arcs}_{v \to u} (u) \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```